# Elastic search searching for any phrase from a Set of phrases

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am filling a Set with this values:

```
set.add("hey michael");
set.add("hey john");
```

Then index two messages:

```
    mes.add("hey john how are you?");
    mes.add("hey michael how are you?");

    for(int i=0;i<mes.size();i++)
    {
        test.put("tag",mes.get(i));
        client.prepareIndex("test", "test",String.valueOf((i+1))).setSource(test).execute().actionGet();
    }
```

What i want is to find the messages that contain one of the phrases in the set.
That is in this example both messages match the criteria

So far i tried the match query:

```
MatchQueryBuilder q =   QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tag",set).operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.OR);
    System.out.println(q.toString());
```

which looks like this:

> {
>     "match" : {
>       "tag" : {
>         "query" : [ "hey john", "hey michael" ],
>         "type" : "boolean",
>         "operator" : "OR"
>       }
>     }
>   }

and the termsQuery:

```
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("tag",set))
```

with no luck - it returnes 0 hits

What query should i use? example will be very helpful

Comment: `tag` needs to be a `not_analyzed` field for that to work.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks. can you explain a bit why it should work with not_analyzed, also any guidance regarding making tag not_analyzed using java api

Comment: @AndreiStefan just saw "PhraseQuery" can it be suitable for my case?